# InternetErrorDlg does not save password

Tags: delphi, wininet

I use InternetErrorDlg to request login/password( it's delphi, but i think it's clear)

```
function ShowLoginDlg(Request: HINTERNET): boolean;
var
  DlgError: Cardinal;
begin
  DlgError := InternetErrorDlg(GetDesktopWindow, Request, 0,
    FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS or
    FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS or
    FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA, PPointer(nil)^{like NULL in C/C++});
  if DlgError = ERROR_CANCELLED then Abort; // Abort raises exception
  if (DlgError <> ERROR_SUCCESS) and (DlgError <> ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY) then
    RaiseLastOSError(DlgError); // RaiseLastOSError raises exception
  Result := DlgError = ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY;
end;

while True do
begin
  SendRequest(Request);
  if not ((GetStatusCode(Request) = 401) and ShowLoginDlg(Request)) do
    Continue;
  CheckStatusCode(Request); // raises exception if status code >= 400
end;
```

and have one problem. Even if user check the "Save password", the password is not 
really saved. So, when I close and open my program again, web resource returns 401 to me and I have to show login dialog again.

Any ideas??

If I add FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS by RRUZ's advise, I don't get any effects. my callback isn't called and password isn't saved.

```
function InternetAuthNotifyCallback(
      dwContext: DWORD; // as passed to InternetErrorDlg
      dwReturn: DWORD; // error code: success, resend, or cancel
      lpReserved: Pointer // reserved: will be set to null
      ): DWORD; stdcall; // stdcall, is it right?
begin
  Result := 0; // What do I have to do??
end;

  type
    PFN_AUTH_NOTIFY = function(
      dwContext:DWORD;
      dwReturn:DWORD;
      lpReserved:Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
    PINTERNET_AUTH_NOTIFY_DATA = ^INTERNET_AUTH_NOTIFY_DATA;
    INTERNET_AUTH_NOTIFY_DATA = packed record
      cbStruct: DWORD;
      dwOptions: DWORD;
      pfnNotify: PFN_AUTH_NOTIFY;
      dwContext: PDWORD;
    end;

  function ShowLoginDlg(Request: HINTERNET): boolean;
  var
    DlgError: Cardinal;
    PData: Pointer;
    Data: INTERNET_AUTH_NOTIFY_DATA;
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@Data, SizeOf(Data));
    Data.cbStruct := SizeOf(Data);
    Data.pfnNotify := InternetAuthNotifyCallback;
    PData := @Data; // if I set PData := Pointer(1) there is **not** AV!!!!
          // InternetErrorDlg don't use this parameter???
    DlgError := InternetErrorDlg(Application.MainForm.Handle, Request, 0,
      FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS or
      FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS or
      FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA or
      FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS,
      PData); // really InternetErrorDlg get pointer to PData, because in Delphi this param is passed by ref
    if DlgError = ERROR_CANCELLED then Abort;
    if (DlgError <> ERROR_SUCCESS) and (DlgError <> ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY) then
      RaiseLastOSError(DlgError);
    Result := DlgError = ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation about the [`InternetErrorDlg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function , you must include the 
**FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS** flag in the method call.

> FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS
>
> Serializes authentication dialog boxes for concurrent requests on a
>   password cache entry. The lppvData parameter should contain the
>   address of a pointer to an INTERNET_AUTH_NOTIFY_DATA structure, and
>   the client should implement a thread-safe, non-blocking callback
>   function.